# Ursprung von „Das wäre doch gelacht“?

Tags: etymology, idiom

Ist etwas einfach oder müsste zu schaffen sein, dann *wäre es doch gelacht*, wenn das nicht klappte!

Die Bedeutung ist klar, aber woher kommt der Ausdruck?
[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=w%C3%A4re%20doch%20gelacht&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cw%C3%A4re%20doch%20gelacht%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bw%C3%A4re%20doch%20gelacht%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BW%C3%A4re%20doch%20gelacht%3B%2Cc0) findet die ersten Beispiele in den 1920ern (was nichts Endgültiges über die tatsächliche Entstehungszeit aussagt) und im Eintrag *[lachen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GL00081#XGL00081)* im Grimm ist die Redewendung nicht verzeichnet.
Der [Redensarten-Index](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~Das%20waere%20doch%20gelacht!&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) gibt keine Herkunft an.

Entstammt die Redewendung einem literarischen Werk?
Falls nicht, wann und wo (Region, Varietät) ist sie entstanden?

**edit:** Ich wage hier einmal, einen Kommentar vom Nutzer [Hubert Schölnast](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1487/hubert-sch%C3%B6lnast) verbatim an diese Frage anzuhängen, da ihm bei der Redewendung Besonderheiten aufgefallen sind, die ich gar nicht bemerkt hatte:

> Interessante Frage, zumal die Phrase nur im Konjunktiv und nur mit Modalpartikel funktioniert. Das wird verwendet: "das wäre doch gelacht", "das wäre ja gelacht". Das findet man nie: "das wäre gelacht", "das ist gelacht", "das ist doch/ja gelacht". Auch interessant: Das Partizip II von lachen wird eigentlich nicht mit einer Form von sein verwendet, sondern mit einer Form von haben: "Ist das dein Kind? Mit kam vor es hätte gelacht." Nicht aber "... dein Kind? Mit kam vor es wäre gelacht."

Comment: Ein Verdacht, dem man einmal nachgehen könnte (und sei's nur, um ihn auszuwischen): Bei vielen Redewendungen im Deutschen, die semantisch schwer erklärbar sind, steht am Ende ein Ausdruck aus dem Jiddischen/Hebräischen dahinter, der von dieser Sprachen Unkundigen dann falsch oder volksetymologisch eingedeutsch wurde. Vielleicht ist das auch hier so?

Comment: @Christian Kennst Du zufällig so einen Ausdruck in Jiddisch / Hebräisch?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ   Wenn ich einen kennte, hätte ich ihn natürlich schon vorgeschlagen. Das wäre ja gelacht!

Comment: Im Gegenteil gilt der Spruch auch, wenn etwas nur schwerlig zu bewerkstelligen ist, weil es leicht zu verhindern ist. Dann wäre einerseits das Verhindern *gelacht* in deinem erst genannten Sinne, aber soweit ambivalent auch das Widererwarten eine Überraschung. Darum könnte auch die negative Wertung ursprünglich sein. Ich könnte mich jetzt den Spekulationsversuchen anschließen, wir sind hier aber nicht bei "Was bin ich?" mit Norbert Blümle; Ein "Ich hab's doch gewusst" im Nachgang wäre reiner Selbstbetrug. Ginge es um Double Dutch oder Rotwelsch, wäre ein Deutsch-Forum die falsche Anlaufstelle.

Comment: Interessante Frage, zumal die Phrase nur im Konjunktiv und nur mit Modalpartikel funktioniert. Das wird verwendet: *"das wäre doch gelacht", "das wäre ja gelacht".* Das findet man nie: *"das wäre gelacht", "das ist gelacht", "das ist doch/ja gelacht".* Auch interessant: Das Partizip II von *lachen* wird eigentlich nicht mit einer Form von *sein* verwendet, sondern mit einer Form von *haben*: "Ist das dein Kind? *Mit kam vor es **hätte** gelacht."* Nicht aber *"... dein Kind? Mit kam vor es **wäre** gelacht."*

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich habe deinen Kommentar einfach mal an die Frage gehängt, da du interessante Aspekte ansprichst.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Es könnte sich um eine Struktur handeln, die analog zu „Das wäre doch komisch“ (oder zu einem anderen Adjektiv) gebildet wurde.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, ob die Aussage nur mit Modalpartikel funktioniert. Es gibt zumindest [genug](https://books.google.de/books?id=nIlBAQAAMAAJ&q=%22das+w%C3%A4re+gelacht%22&dq=%22das+w%C3%A4re+gelacht%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO-_-h_5PkAhXJ6aQKHThCDZE4ChDoAQgyMAI) (historische) [Beispiele](https://books.google.de/books?id=LFE8AQAAMAAJ&q=%22das+w%C3%A4re+gelacht%22&dq=%22das+w%C3%A4re+gelacht%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJwqvW_pPkAhUF_aQKHcckDRkQ6AEIMDAB) für ohne. Auch aus der Zeit als die Aussage wohl Verbreitung fanden. Wobei laut ngram die Verwendungskurve erst in den 50ern auseinandergeht.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Dann wäre das wohl was mit [Isaak](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaak_(Name))? Saber [kompliziert](http://www.imdialog.org/bp2014/04/03.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wahrscheinlich rührt die Wendung aus dem alten Gebrauch des Verbes »lachen« mit Genitiv her, der leider erloschen ist und von der Präposition »über« verdrängt wurde. So heißt es etwa bei Lessing im Nathan:

> Hab ich des schönen Traums nicht gleich gelacht?

Oder in Grillparzer »König Ottokars Glück und Ende«

> Der mir gestohlen, was mein eigen war;
>     Gelacht des Herolds, den er mir gesandt,
>     Den Mann, den er beschützt, zum Tod verdammt

Diese Verwendung mit Genitiv ist ganz parallel zu Verben wie »spotten«, »denken« etc. Also:

> Ich habe deiner gedacht, du hast meiner gespottet.

Daraus wäre die Wendung: »Dessen (oder des) wäre (doch/ja) gelacht« leicht zu erklären. Weil dieser Gebrauch des Genitivs aber mit der Zeit  ungewöhnlich oder gar unverständlich wurde, ist er möglicherweise durch das nächstliegende Wort, in diesem Falle »das«, ersetzt worden.

Comment: Das ist eine schöne Theorie, an die ich gern glauben möchte. Allerdings würde ich dann erwarten, dass es Belege für die Verwendung der Wendung mit dessen / des gibt, was weder der Grimm (und dort stehen wirklich viele Verwendungen von *lachen*) noch allgemeine Suchmaschinen (Suche nach Zeichenkette) bestätigen.

Comment: Zwar steht die Bemerkung der unterschiedlichen Hilfsverben weiterhin entgegen, außer man setzt *würde* anstatt *wär' do'* an. Vergleicht man [gelingen](https://dwds.de/wb/gelingen) oder bspw NL [gelikt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gelikt) (DE *geleckt*) könnte man ungewiss auf ältere Herkunft schließen, wogegen DWDS/*lachen* erst "19. JH.", "Studentensprache" für die Redewendung verzeichnet

Comment: @JohnHennig Da war mein Kommentar missverständlich: Ich wollte nicht die Verwendung von *lachen* + Genitiv (und dessen Gebrauch mit *dessen*) anzweifeln, sondern dass diese Konstruktion („dessen wäre doch gelacht“) in der Bedeutung „das wäre doch gelacht“ belegt ist – das gibt der Kontext des Lessingzitats nicht her.

Comment: @Philipp Ein direkter Beleg ist hier zu viel verlangt, weil es selbst für die eindeutig umgangssprachliche Wendung »Das wäre gelacht«, die übrigens durch aus ohne »doch/ja« vorkommt, in der Schriftsprache sehr wenige Belege gibt. Mir fallen aus dem Stande nur drei ein: (1) Brecht: Dreigroschenoper, Eifersuchtsduett: »Ha, das wäre doch gelacht, wenn sich wer aus dir was macht«. (2) Rosenow: Die im Schatten leben: »Mit Ihnen ist noch fertig zu werden. Das wäre gelacht!«. (3) Tucholsky. Deshalb bleibt mein Vorschlag eine Hypothese… –

Comment: während "wäre gelungen" geläufig ist findet auch "hat gelungen" einige Treffer aus 18./19 JH. Ich ziehe meinen Einwand soweit zurück. Schade, ich hatte schon eine Analogie zu *smile*, *schmulen*, *schummeln*, doch ohne deren Verwandschaft zu erforschen, vermutet.